# JQgrid custom add a row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

i have one button out side of jqGrid. when i click the button it should hit the inside the jqGrid add button. is it possible.

```
<input type="button" id="btnCustomAdd" value="Add"/>
```

when i click the above button inside jqGrid button should hit. is it possible.

**jqGrid:**

```
 $("#Datasourcegrid").jqGrid({
              postData: { CAId: function () { return $('#hdnchnAppId').val(); } },
                colNames: ['DataSourceId', 'Title','Sort Order'],
                colModel: [
                            { name: 'DataSourceId', index: 'DataSourceId', align: 'left', key: true, editable: false, hidden: true, search:false,width: '10'},
                            { name: 'DataSourceTitle', index: 'DataSourceTitle', sortable: true, align: 'left', width: '400',editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules: { required: true },stype:'text', search:true,searchoptions:{sopt:['eq']}},
                            { name: 'SortOrder', index: 'SortOrder', sortable: true, align: 'left', width: '100',editable: true, hidden: true, edittype: 'text', editrules:{number:true, required:true}, search:false},

 ],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way, if you meant that just new empty row shows

```
$(function(){
   $("#btnCustomAdd").on("click", function(event){
        $("#grid").jqGrid("addRowData", rowid, { Id: rowid});
        //OR
        $("#grid").addRow(rowid, parameters);
        //OR new API
        $("#grid").jqGrid('addRow',parameters);
        //FORM EDIT EXAMPLE
        $("#grid").editGridRow( "new", parameters );
        //OR new API
        $("#grid").jqGrid('editGridRow', "new", parameters );
    });
});

parameters =
{
   rowID : "new_row",
   initdata : {},
   position :"first",
   useDefValues : false,
   useFormatter : false,
   addRowParams : {extraparam:{}}
}
```

**EDIT:** Added form-edit example you can read more about form editing [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#adding_row)

Comment: Row id is your own new ID you set it as -1 or increment the previous one thats your custom indicator by which you can later uniquely select row or edit it etc.

Comment: i have given as -1. but not getting. i have added the code for jqGrid, can you give the solution through that jqGrid. Here need to display add form(popup) with title and sortorder.

Comment: Ok didn't know you have form editing, I added form edit example and some additional resource